# Easier way to perform the same steps multiple times on different vectors?

Tags: r

As part of my assignment for Experimental Design and Analysis, we are tasked with running a series of classification methods (none of which we've been taught to use before!) on [this dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/banknote+authentication). Our response to be studied is the proportion of correct predictions made by the classification method on the test set - in order to satisfy replication, I've split the data into training and test sets 5 times, and fit a logistic model to each training set.

I understand how to do all this, but it creates the problem that each line I write/operation I perform, I have to write out 5 times - I will also have to do this with the other 4 classification methods (once I understand how to implement them!), and if we decide that we need more Test/Training splits for whatever reason, I'll have to write out even more lines!

It just looks and feels needlessly ugly, and I feel like there must be a less tedious way of accomplishing this.

This is what my code looks like:

```
banknotedata <- read.csv("data_banknote_authentication.csv")
colnames(banknotedata) <- c("Variance","Skewness", "Kurtosis", "Entropy", "Class")
```

```
set.seed(420)
samplesize <- floor(NROW(banknotedata)*0.75)
TrainIndex1 <- sample(NROW(banknotedata), samplesize)
TrainIndex2 <- sample(NROW(banknotedata), samplesize)
TrainIndex3 <- sample(NROW(banknotedata), samplesize)
TrainIndex4 <- sample(NROW(banknotedata), samplesize)
TrainIndex5 <- sample(NROW(banknotedata), samplesize)

Train1 <- banknotedata[TrainIndex1,]
Train2 <- banknotedata[TrainIndex2,]
Train3 <- banknotedata[TrainIndex3,]
Train4 <- banknotedata[TrainIndex4,]
Train5 <- banknotedata[TrainIndex5,]

Test1 <- banknotedata[-TrainIndex1,]
Test2 <- banknotedata[-TrainIndex2,]
Test3 <- banknotedata[-TrainIndex3,]
Test4 <- banknotedata[-TrainIndex4,]
Test5 <- banknotedata[-TrainIndex5,]
```

```
logitmodel1 <- glm(Class ~.,family=binomial, data=Train1)
logitmodel2 <- glm(Class ~., family=binomial, data=Train2)
logitmodel3 <- glm(Class ~., family=binomial, data=Train3)
logitmodel4 <- glm(Class ~., family=binomial, data=Train4)
logitmodel5 <- glm(Class ~., family=binomial, data=Train5)
```

```
logitprobs1 <- predict(logitmodel1, type="response", newdata = Test1)
logitprobs2 <- predict(logitmodel2, type="response", newdata = Test2)
logitprobs3 <- predict(logitmodel3, type="response", newdata = Test3)
logitprobs4 <- predict(logitmodel4, type="response", newdata = Test4)
logitprobs5 <- predict(logitmodel5, type="response", newdata = Test5)
```

```
logitpred1 <- round(logitprobs1)
logitpred2 <- round(logitprobs2)
logitpred3 <- round(logitprobs3)
logitpred4 <- round(logitprobs4)
logitpred5 <- round(logitprobs5)
```

```
sum(logitpred1 == Test1$Class)/NROW(Test1)
sum(logitpred2 == Test2$Class)/NROW(Test2)
sum(logitpred3 == Test3$Class)/NROW(Test3)
sum(logitpred4 == Test4$Class)/NROW(Test4)
sum(logitpred5 == Test5$Class)/NROW(Test5)
```

This is really just 7 operations, but each one has to be written out 5 times, making it look like much more than it actually is, and it's just tedious to do. So I'm not looking for help with the actual assignment per se, but I'm hoping there might be a simpler and more visually pleasing way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing, sorry! I've gone and done that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have to do something repetitive, functions are the way to go.
In your example, you can do sth like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

banknotedata <- read.csv("data_banknote_authentication.csv")
colnames(banknotedata) <- c("Variance","Skewness", "Kurtosis", "Entropy", "Class")

set.seed(420)
samplesize <- floor(NROW(banknotedata)*0.75)

classify <- function(df, samplesize){
  TrainIndex <- sample(NROW(df), samplesize)
  Train <- df[TrainIndex,]
  Test <- df[-TrainIndex,]
  logitmodel <- glm(Class ~.,family=binomial, data=Train)
  logitprobs <- predict(logitmodel, type="response", newdata = Test)
  logitpred <- round(logitprobs)
  return(sum(logitpred == Test$Class)/NROW(Test))
}
```

If you want to run the following function 5 times, you can easily do it through `purrr`'s `map` function.

```
map(1:5, ~classify(banknotedata, samplesize))
```

That way you will get a list with your results.
From this point on, you just have to modify the function depending on what you need.
Another thing: consider whether it would be better to split your data using `createDataPartition` from `caret` as it should balance the classes between training and testing sets in case of uneven classes.

Comment: I copied your code but when I try to use map() I get the error


 `Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : unused argument (samplesize)` 

and when I don't use samplesize

`Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : invalid 'size' argument`

Also how do I add line breaks to comments on here?

Comment: sorry about that! I've fixed the syntax now and it should work. And you can't add line breaks in comments.